# unable to signout to specific path using devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i have three devise :

```
devise_for :hrs
devise_for :employes
devise_for :authorizes
```

If i signed in as `:authorize` in `application_controller.rb`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(authorize)
  auth_main_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(authorize)
   new_authorize_session_path
end
def after_sign_in_path_for(employe)
   employee_emain_path
end

 def after_sign_out_path_for(employe)
   new_employe_session_path
 end
def after_sign_in_path_for(hr)
   hrs_hhome_path
 end
 def after_sign_out_path_for(hr)
   new_hr_session_path
 end
```

and in `application.html.erb` code for `sign_out` button is:

```
<%= link_to "SIGNOUT", destroy_authorize_session_path, :method => :delete ,:data => { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
```

**Till here it works perfectly, but as soon as i add the controller for other two devise it gives error**

What should i change to the button so that it `destroy the session for the current_session`
If i `signed in` as `:hr`, then clicking on `signout` it should render to specified path. Same should apply for the other devise models.

**ERROR**

If i press on `sign_out` button i get error when i log_in as employee or hr. i want that `if i have login as employee then it should destroy the employee_session for that what changes should i do.

thank you.

Comment: what error - please add it to your question. does any signout work?

Comment: yes the current signout works. but i have 2 more devise.

Comment: please post the error(s) and when they occur

Comment: done changes do check

Comment: please the error from `log/development.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a method to return the correct path for the logged in user.

For example, in your ApplicationController you can add a method to get the correct sign-out path for the current user, something like

```
def sign_out_path
 if hr_signed_in?
  destroy_hr_session_url
 elsif employe_signed_in?
  destroy_employe_session_url
 else
  destroy_authorize_session_url
 end
end
```

Then in your html, use this method instead of the path.

```
<%= link_to "SIGNOUT", sign_out_path, :method => :delete ,:data => { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
```

You should really add a method to check if any user is signed-in, and only display the sign-out link then.